# Can't deploy microservice to cumulocity platform

Tags: cumulocity

I'm trying to deploy a microservice to the cumulocity platform. I tried it manually by creating an application as descriped in the guide ([Microservice SDK for Java](https://cumulocity.com/guides/microservice-sdk/java/#run-locally)). The application was created successfully but the upload of the zip file failed with the error "No such file or directory". The utility tool from [Microservice package and deploy](https://cumulocity.com/guides/reference/microservice-package) failed with the same error. (see below)

```
./microservice deploy -n hello-world .....
[INFO] Read input
[INFO] Start deployment
[INFO] Application with name hello-world not found, add new application
[INFO] Application name: hello-world id: 878
[INFO] Upload file hello-world.zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 98.7M    0   204  100 98.7M      1   563k  0:02:59  0:02:59 --:--:--  165k
[WARNING] error durning upload
Failed to deploy microservice application : No such file or directory
[INFO] End deployment
```

Is there something I am missing? I created the microservice step by step according to the description in the cumulocity guide. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the structure of the zip you are trying to upload.

Comment: It's the zip file produced by the hello-world-microservice example maven project. It consists of the image.tar and the cumulocity.json.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help you. We also had this issue and from what I can recall this was related to the name of the package, that's why we set everything in the pom file:

```xml
<build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.nsn.cumulocity.clients-java</groupId>
                <artifactId>microservice-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${c8y.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packageName>${microservice.name}</packageName>
                    <skipMicroserviceUpload>false</skipMicroserviceUpload>

                    <application>
                        <name>${microservice.name}</name>
                    </application>
                    <credentials>
                        <url>${microservice.deploy.url}</url>
                        <username>${microservice.deploy.username}</username>
                        <password>${microservice.deploy.password}</password>
                    </credentials>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <name>${microservice.name}</name>
                            <image>${microservice.name}</image>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```